# How to fold sheets after ironing?

Tags: bedroom

My mother always would ask for another person in order to fold sheets after ironing them. Now that I live alone, I have great difficulty in doing that and usually I end up with terrible results. Is there a way that I can do it alone and have nicely folded sheets?

Comment: What do you mean by "terrible results"?

Comment: Flat sheets, I presume?

Comment: @MatthewRock I mean that they look more like this https://laineymcblog.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/martha-after.jpg :P

Comment: @Stephie yes, flat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the sheet is ironed flat, gather the four corners in one hand while using your free hand to pull the folds with a bit of tension. This makes the sheet 1/4 its spread size. Grip the sheet in this way and shake to set the folds. Place the quartered sheet on your bed and continue to fold it gathering the sides until you have the desired folded size.

< —————— >
[image]

Most all sheets have a trim or different treatment for the head-end and for the foot of the bed-end.

One way to start is by putting the two corners of the head-end together, overlapping them precisely and holding them together with your strong hand.

Work you way along the length of the sheet until you get to the other end and do the same thing without letting go of the two corners you have.

Match the four corners as shown in the diagram or if the sheet has become twisted straighten it out at this point and gather the four corners. Hold them tightly.

With your free hand, pull the folds out, straightening them. Let the sheet hang so that you can grip along the top to shake it, setting the folds.

In the diagram, I'd be holding the corners with my right hand and using my left to pull the top of the sheet taught in the direction of the arrows.

It will look similar to the diagram only more carefully aligned.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. I don't understand how exactly to gather the four corners in one hand. All the corners should touch each other?

Comment: @papakias All the corners and sides should be carefully aligned and matched. I had to distort the drawing so that you could see the "folds" or it would simply look like a square.

Answer (score 2):

You can spread a sheet out flat on the bed, and fold it over itself at your own pace, using the bed as your "helper" in lieu of another person.

Answer (score 0):

I am 79 and live alone.Wash the sheets in machine. When it stops take it out, position the lines of the sheet and carefully fold and match into a rectangular shape. Keep like that and lay it on chair or frame still damp (shake well before doing this). If not needed for a while leave it to dry, then put away. It will not need ironing. It may take several days to dry.

Comment: Hi Carole, Welcome to lifehacks.stackexchange. If I left something damp for more than a day or two, it would start to acquire a mildew odour. A used towel must be completely dry before I put it into the 'dirty' laundry to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This way is for if you have no horizontal surface, or if the floor is dirty or wet.

Stand on a stool or chair. Grab two corners of your sheet and hold them over your head. Shake and stretch till it's flat. Now quickly put the two corners together, hold them in one hand and grab the fold in the other hand, shake again. Repeat. Now hold the sheet up with one hand, quickly put the other hand in the middle and let it fold down over it. Adjust, shake, repeat.